# How can I access the edit environment variables window?

Tags: windows-10, python, environment-variables

I can't seem to access the edit environment variable editor, I instead get the edit system variable editor when I click on edit. Looking at the other questions, I maybe deleted the original path when I tried to install python by making python the path?

Running `echo %PATH%` just gives `C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311;C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311`

I also don't have file history on

[What I see when I Click edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyVig.png)

Edit: yeah it looks like I accidently deleted the original path, is there any way to get it back?